# phpMyAdmin is showing 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache-http-server, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have just changed my `www` folders permission to `777` using this command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 www
```

And now when I try to open `phpMyAdmin` in browser and it is not opening and showing `403 Forbidden` Error `You don't have permission to access /phpMyAdmin/index.php on this server.`

I try to change its permission to 744 but it still displays this error. I tried also to restart the apache after doing this changes but no luck.

How can I open `phpMyadmin` by changing its permission??

Comment: Knowing the apache configuration for phpnyadmin would probably help!

Comment: @slhck I found the proper file permission for my `phpMyAdmin`. see answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the permission to `755` and now it is working properly.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 phpMyAdmin
```